# Why server cannot output contents of buffer?

Tags: php, zend-framework, unix, permissions, wamp

On my local machine server I am using zend and within a view, I make a buffer to store the contents displayed from the view.

I save it on my local server, in the public folder and everything is good,

I am on windows by the way.

now when I move it to the server, it does not write the file 9save the file).

I have given write chmod -777 permissions to the view file but it still does not work.

Do I need to give the controller and model the same permissions as well?

Comment: the problem is that the file is not written or that the output is not buffered (and sent to the screen instead) ?

Comment: It does both on my local machine though...it just sends to the screen on the remote

Comment: in that case the problem is the output buffering, not writing to the file.

Comment: check the configuration values (http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php) including the output buffer size

Comment: your server is probably just nixing write to the web root (a very sane configuration) you don't need to change permissions of the php file doing the writing but to the folder that you are writing too.